# Java code to register a new user in SIP(Session Initiation Protocol)

Tags: android, sip

I am trying to create an Android application using SIP in order to enable voice conferencing. What is the java code to register a new user? And how do I communicate with a proxy server?

Comment: what have your tried?

Answer (score 0):

You should check Android's SIP test application that you can locate at:

`<ANDROID_SDK_PATH>/samples/<ANDROID_SDK_VERSION>/SipDemo`

Please, also check [Android SIP stack official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)